# What is this equipment under the nose of this aircraft?

Tags: airline-operations, equipment

From the news of the [Singapore Airline A330 nose gear collapse](https://web.archive.org/web/20151012202850/https://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/singapore/singapore-airlines-plane/2184022.html) at Changi, I noticed some equipment under the nose part of the aircraft, which  somewhat damaged the radome when the nose gear collapsed.

It looks like some kind of ladder. What is it and what is it used for?

Note: it is during routine airline operation.

[image: picture of equipment]

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I added a still from a news video

Comment: Here, [avherald](http://avherald.com/h?article=48da23e8) link. This is more reliable for aviation incident reports than mainstream media, because the information is more carefully verified. In this particular case it does not have more information, except a bit in comments, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The report says the aircraft was undergoing a landing gear system check. The equipment looks like a trolley-mounted inspection ladder that could well have been used during such a check.

Answer (score 3):

As per the report published in the website:

> In response to queries, SIA said the nose gear of the aircraft retracted while the aircraft was at Gate A17 undergoing a landing gear system check at around 8am on Sunday morning. At the time of the incident, there were no passengers or crew on board, but an engineer was on the aircraft.

Aircraft was undergoing on a landing gear system check, so engineer is using the ladder to reach out the complete system.

Yes, it is ladder. Also you can see some other picture which shows the door tore apart due to air bridge because of landing gear crashing.